# count 2 values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about an sql query i want to make.
Supose i have an column with the follow values in **table: school** with **column: grades**.

```
grades
9
9
4
4
4
1
1
```

Now i want to count how many times there is an 9 and how many times there is an 4 in column grades and then sum(2+3).
so the output of my sql query will be 5.
I want to count only the 4 and 9 values.

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`.  `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SCHOOL WHERE grades IN (4,9)
```

In response to the comment, you could try summing a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
    SUM( CASE WHEN grades IN (4,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS MyFirstColumn,
    SUM( CASE WHEN grades NOT IN (4,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS MySecondColumn
FROM school
```

For clarity, you may want to try running the below query without sums to make sure you understand what you're implementing:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN grades IN (4,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MyFirstColumn,
    CASE WHEN grades NOT IN (4,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MySecondColumn
FROM school
```

Should you be interested in only 4, 9 and 1 grades, I would recommend adding a `WHERE` clause at the end as you'll notice the second column will count up rows without a 4 or a 9 (this may include grades other than just 1).

```
WHERE grades IN (1,4,9)
```

Comment: This is correct but i want also to count the number 1 apart, so i will get 2 columns in the output. 

Column1 = 5(4,9), Column2(1) = 2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly,  you are counting the numbers of either 4 or 9. Here is the query.

```
Select count(1) From yourtable Where grades in (4,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of going about it:

```
SELECT 
SUM(grades IN (4,9)) AS Column1,
SUM(grades =1) AS Column2 
FROM school;
```